# AWS CloudFront and Invalidation Delay Leads to Repeated On-demand Image Resize

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, image-resizing

I am using AWS S3 (static website hosting) in order to perform on-demand image resizing. I configured my S3 bucket to redirect to my lambda function when a requested object is not present. The lambda function finds the path of an original image, downloads, resizes, and uploads it to S3. Finally, it runs CloudFront invalidation before it redirects the request to the resized image location. (I used CloudFront distribution to run it on https. Otherwise, the unsecured icon appears in the browser bar) The problem is, even after the resized object is uploaded, the CloudFront has not yet distributed the presence of the resized object and it repeats the procedure multiple times (about three times). It consumes more of the lambda power that leads to a bigger bill. Any thought or recommendations?
I followed instructions below to set this up.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/